# .htaccess: append subdomain as query to existing queries

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to append the subdomain as a query to eventual existing queries using htaccess.

`http://test.domain.com` should be `http://test.domain.com?x=test`
`http://test.domain.com?id=1` should be `http://test.domain.com?id=1&x=test`

This is what I have done, but it doesn't work and I can figure out why:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
// exclude www.domain.com
RewriteCond %1 !^(www)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^\?]*(?:\?(.*))?$ index.php?$1&x=%1 [L]
```

My understanding was

`[^\?]*` all characters except ?, match 0 or more times

`(?:` start of a non capturing group

`\?` match ? literally

`(.*)` all characters after ? as a group

`)?` end of the non capturing group, match 0 or 1 times

But it does not work. Where is my mistake?

**UPDATE 1:**

I could make it work by using the following rule

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1&x=%1 [QSA,L]
```

`http://test1.domain.com?y=test1` brings me `[x=>test1,y=>test2]`

but

`http://test1.domain.com?y=test1&x=test3` brings me `[x=>test3,y=>test2]`

So it overrides my x value. Is there a way to block that?

**UPDATE 2**

This is the code I'm using now:
RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)([\w-]+)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %1::%{QUERY_STRING} !^(.+?)::x=\1(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&x=%1 [L]
```

Comment: My mistake, should be $1, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Regarding your edit: Can’t you just chose another parameter name instead of `x` – something that is very unlikely to occur as a query string parameter name in the original request …?

Comment: I need to rely on the fact, that the query is definitely the sub domain. So just choosing something unlikely is not secure enough...

Comment: What do you mean by _“that the query is definitely the sub domain”_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)([\w-]+)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %1::%{QUERY_STRING} !^(.+?)::x=\1(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&x=%1 [L]
```

Make sure this is the only rule you have in .htaccess while testing.

Explanation of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)([\w-]+)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %1::%{QUERY_STRING} !^(.+?)::x=\1(?:&|$) [NC]
```

1. We are capturing starting part of hostname from this group: `([\w-]+)` which is denoted by `%1`. Note that we cannot use `%1` in RHS of a condition.
2. We are then appending `%1` and `%{QUERY_STRING}` together in `%1::%{QUERY_STRING}`. Here we could use any other arbitrary delimiter like `##` as well.
3. In RHS we have `^(.+?)::x=\1(?:&|$)` which means `%1` followed by delimiter `::` followd by literal `x=` and then `\1` which is back-reference for `%1` (goup before `::`). `!` before `^` is there to negate the condition. In simple words this condition means execute this rule only if we already don't have `x=subdomain` in `QUERY_STRING`.

Comment: I get an internal server error, but I have to mention that I use cakephp so it might be an issue with cakephp. I removed all other rules...

Comment: In cakephp I have to redirect everything to index.php, can you also help me with this?

Comment: try my updated answer now and check `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`

Comment: I switched `x=%1` and `%{QUERY_STRING}`
Now I have the intended behavior, awesome. Could you give me a little explanation what is happening in the different steps?

Comment: I've added some explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to match the query string content with your RewriteRule’s pattern – that is not possible, it searches only the path component of the requested URL.

But, no worries – there’s an easy solution that helps combine the original query string, and what the pattern matched: The [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag.

So this should do the trick (combined with your existing RewriteConds):

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I added it to the htaccess file and when I enter `http://x.domain.com/a?b=c` I get the following array `['a' => '','b' => 'c']`.
So the x is completely not present

Comment: Using this `RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1&alias=%1 [QSA,L]` does work. But now I have another problem. I will update my question...